# Printing in Java - Media size being ignored

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to use Java Print Services for sending print jobs to printers automatically but its quickly turning into a nightmare. Coming to the problem at hand, here is the code:

```
DocAttributeSet docAset = new HashDocAttributeSet();
                docAset.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
                Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(book, psInFormat, docAset);
                PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                aset.add(new JobName("Test Job Name", null));
                aset.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
                aset.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);
                aset.add(Fidelity.FIDELITY_TRUE);

//                new JobState()
                DocPrintJob job = services[8].createPrintJob();
                try {
                    job.print(myDoc, aset);
    //System.out.println(" Thread " + this.getId() + ": Envío de impresión OK");
                } catch (PrintException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PrototypeMain2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

This code is ignoring the media size completely and printing to the default A4 size paper.

Any helps here is very much appreciated.

Comment: Does the printer actually *have* an NA_LETTER - Box? Do other applications correctly print to it?

Comment: The printer does not have a NA_LETTER box but when I sent a print job choosing paper type as NA_LETTER from adobe it asks me for the paper in manual paper tray. In this case it is showing job's paper type as A4.

Comment: Have you had success with using this attribute anytime?

Comment: Another interesting thing is when I use PrinterJob instead of DocPrintJob it asks me for the paper but prints on the wrong side of the paper(job is one sided and depends on which side its printed on). Any ideas as to what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the printer is taking the default paper based on the preferences I set, so if I set the preferences to use letter size it asks for a letter size page, by default it will print on A4 size paper.